# Manage Managed Rules with AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to change the action on some managed rules in my WAF policy in Azure using AZ CLI but I can't with the commands I have used.

I tried some commands but any doesn't work.

I need help. I just need to change the action on some rules from the OWASP 3.2 ruleset in my WAF policy in Azure. And I must do this action with AZ CLI or with some other mechanism that can be automated.

I tried change the action for the rules with these commands:

- az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rules update --> ERROR: 'update' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
- az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rules set --> ERROR: 'set' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
- az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rules rule-set update --> I cannot change a action. I only can update the version of ruleset or change the name for a rule.

Also I tried az network application-gateway waf-policy update --managed-rules, but I don't understand very well this command.

I just need to change the action on some rules from the OWASP 3.2 ruleset in my WAF policy in Azure. And I must do this action with AZ CLI or with some other mechanism that can be automated.

Please I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to change the action on some managed rules in my WAF policy in Azure using AZ CLI.

You can update the action for each rule using the `az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule rule-set update` command. Specify the rule `IDs` and the desired action for each rule.

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule rule-set update --policy-name "<Policy-Name>" -g "<Resource-Group-Name>" --type Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet --version 3.2 --group-name REQUEST-921-PROTOCOL-ATTACK --rule rule-id=921130 --rule rule-id=921160
```

**Output:**

Successfully updated `Rule ID` and `ruleset type`.

[image]

Make sure you have the latest version of the `Azure CLI` installed to access the required commands and functionality.

Reference:   [az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule rule-set update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/waf-policy/managed-rule/rule-set?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-application-gateway-waf-policy-managed-rule-rule-set-update) and [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-crs-rulegroups-rules)